# Trying to use hover to make an image disappear but text is in the way

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

On tumblr I am trying to add an image to the bottom of the page that will disappear when moused over. As it disappears I have a block of text the transitions to appear in its place. Right now both are doing these things, but when the text block is moused over the image reappears. I want it to stay completely transparent.

This is in it's current state

```css
#bite
#bite a{
display:block
}
#bite .death {
margin-top:0px;filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
opacity:0;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

#bite:hover .death {
margin-top:0px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
opacity:100;
}

#actualnews {
font-family: 'Rock Salt'; cursive
font-size:5px;
color: #b8b8b8;
width:150px;
height:auto;
padding-top:3px;
border:1px solid#b8b8b8;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-top:10px;
text-align:center;
position:fixed;
    right:145px;
    bottom:70px;
}

#thekey img{
width:150px;
margin-top: -40px;
margin-left: 45px;
position:fixed;
    right:150px;
    bottom:20px;
filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
opacity:100;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}

#thekey img:hover  { 
margin-top:0px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="bite"> 
<div id="thekey"><img src="{image:thekey}"></div>
<div class="death">
<div id="actualnews">
<a href="www.winngstiel.tumblr.com/tagged/mine" font-color:#9d3e78>MY STUFF</a>
<p>
<a href="www.winngstiel.tumblr.com/tagged/edit" font-color:#9d3e78>PRETTY THINGS</a>
</div>
</div></div>
```

As you can see the text is somehow in the way. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am very new to how everything with coding works. Any confusion or questions please ask!

Comment: Are you using a templating language to generate your `html`? (otherwise thats not the correct way you change the `color` of a link). Please also change the `img` `src` so that it is a link to an actual image (preferably the same image) so that we can accurately replicate your troubles

Comment: @haxxxton the image isn't anywhere online so i don't have a link to it since it's saved on my computer. I didn't realize that that's not the right way to change the color of the link so ignore that i guess it's not terribly important.

Comment: best to do link colours in your css. Also for future use, http://placehold.it/ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the selector for the CSS rule that hides the image to trigger on `#bite`'s hover.

```
...
#bite:hover #thekey img  {
...
```

Full code:

```css
#bite
#bite a{
display:block
}
#bite .death {
margin-top:0px;filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
opacity:0;-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

#bite:hover .death {
margin-top:0px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
opacity:100;
}

#actualnews {
font-family: 'Rock Salt'; cursive
font-size:5px;
color: #b8b8b8;
width:150px;
height:auto;
padding-top:3px;
border:1px solid#b8b8b8;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-top:10px;
text-align:center;
position:fixed;
    right:145px;
    bottom:70px;
}

#thekey img{
width:150px;
margin-top: -40px;
margin-left: 45px;
position:fixed;
    right:150px;
    bottom:20px;
filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
opacity:100;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}

#bite:hover #thekey img  { 
margin-top:0px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="bite"> 
<div id="thekey"><img src="{image:thekey}"></div>
<div class="death">
<div id="actualnews">
<a href="www.winngstiel.tumblr.com/tagged/mine" font-color:#9d3e78>MY STUFF</a>
<p>
<a href="www.winngstiel.tumblr.com/tagged/edit" font-color:#9d3e78>PRETTY THINGS</a>
</div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: That works perfectly!! Thank you so much :) would you mind explaining at least a little as to why that works??

Comment: When you hover over an element, it also triggers the hover event of it's parent (and it's parent and so on). Since `#bite` is the parent of both the image you want to hide and the text you want to show when either is hovered over it will trigger the rule.